# Google cloud storage : open browser when create Storage

Tags: java, browser, google-cloud-storage

I use "Google API Services Storage" library.
When I want to create a Storage to create a bucket :

```
private static Storage createStorage(String clientId, String clientSecret, String applicationName, Set<String> scopesList) {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = null;
    Storage storage;
    Credential credential = null;
    VerificationCodeReceiver receiver;

    try {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, scopesList).build();

    receiver = new LocalServerReceiver();
    try {
        credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize(clientId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(applicationName).build();

    return storage;
}
```

Windows opens my browser and display this page :
[image: google message]

The problem is that my code will be used on a server, so I wish that this step is automatic. What to do?

Comment: use a service account instead of Oauth2 if you are only accessing your own information.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you should use [Service Account Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) for a program running on a server. This generates a private key file, which you must keep secured, that you install on your server. The OAuth web flows should only be used when acting on behalf of a user on a website or installed application.

Answer (score 0):

To use oauth2 on server.
Go to Google console : [google console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Credentials
Create new Client ID
Service account
Create Client ID
Generate new p12 key.

And use documentation : [doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwtsample_java)